# Ubuntu (dual boot) sometimes does not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows on my new ASUS Zenbook 13 UX333F and have had many issues. Most noticeable is that when the grub screen loads and I select Ubuntu, sometimes the grub text disappears and nothing else happens. I have tried waiting for a long time but literally nothing happens, no error text is shown either.

The first time I noticed this I was the first time I had powered off my laptop since installing Ubuntu (after setting up everything..) and I thought something was broken so I reinstalled it (set everything up again..) and it happened again. However, I tried restarting my laptop multiple times and suddenly after the 5th time it showed some terminal text and then worked!

Since then, every time I power off my laptop I have to try booting Ubuntu, wait and see nothing happen, restart and try again a seemingly random number of times (between 0 and 15) until finally it works. I managed to capture the error text in [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj3Qu.jpg) [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGjra.jpg), I think it is the same every time. I hope someone can tell me how to fix this.

It might be worth mentioning that I have some other problems with Ubuntu on this laptop that I never had with my old ASUS:

- My sound did not work at all, neither headphones nor speakers. I fixed this by upgrading to Kernel 5.0.8 via the ukuu command-line tool.
- It does not hibernate or even sleep, I have followed a number of instructions to fix this but nothing seems to work. The battery drains really fast while the lid is closed.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 multiple times (also tried 19.05), updated the kernel to multiple versions and nothing helped.

Why can't I have a smooth, stress-free Ubuntu experience on this new laptop?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried updating your motherboard bios to the latest version? I ask this because the first pic has "acpi bios error(bug)" here is a link to ASUS site where you can dl it https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-13-UX333FA/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Now it doesn't load Kernel 5.0.8, but 5.0.0 works perfectly! Thank you (sorry for the delayed reply).

Comment: However, I think Kernel 5.0.8 was important for the sound to work because when I tried to play a video after booting 5.0.0, it had a weird 'tinny' sound to it before dying out completely.